# Get xpath() to return empty values

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a situation where I have a lot of `<b>` tags:

```
<b>12</b>
<b>13</b>
<b>14</b>
<b></b>
<b>121</b>
```

As you can see, the second last tag is empty.  When I call:

```
sel.xpath('b/text()').extract()
```

Which gives me:

```
['12', '13', '14', '121']
```

I would like to have:

```
['12', '13', '14', '', '121']
```

Is there a way to get the empty value?

---

My current work around is to call:

```
sel.xpath('b').extract()
```

And then parsing through each html tag myself  (the empty tags are here, which is what I want).

Comment: I'm not sure that's a *workaround*, I think it's what you have to do. You're drawing a distinction between `<b/>` and `<b></b>`, and XML has no semantic for the distinction. The empty element `b` exists, but it has no anonymous text node child in either case.

Comment: It's really hard to search for documentation proving something doesn't exist. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where it is okay to manually strip the tags and get the text. You can use [`remove_tags()`](https://github.com/scrapy/w3lib/blob/master/w3lib/html.py#L137) function provided by [`w3lib`](https://github.com/scrapy/w3lib):

```
>>> from w3lib.html import remove_tags
>>> map(remove_tags, sel.xpath('//b').extract())
[u'12', u'13', u'14', u'', u'121']
```

Note that `w3lib` is a [Scrapy dependency](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/setup.py#L125) and is used internally. No need to install it separately.

Also, it would be better to use [`Scrapy` Input and Output Processors](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#declaring-input-and-output-processors) here. Continue using `sel.xpath('b')` and define an input processor. For example, you can define it for specific `Field`s for the `Item` class:

```
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import MapCompose
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from w3lib.html import remove_tags

class MyItem(Item):
    my_field = Field(input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags))
```

Comment: This is a more elegant solution than what I was doing, thanks.

Comment: an all XPath solution would be `[e.xpath('string()').extract()[0] for e in sel.xpath('//b')]`

Comment: all elements  = [e.root.text or 'size-not-found' for e in sel.xpath('.//b')]