# Does Python xpath getall() also have a default value param?

Tags: python, xpath

I am extracting two columns of data, the logic is expecting a 2 element array. But getall() seems to ignore the first element (because it is empty) resulting in a 1 value array instead of 2.

## question

How can I force getall() or the code to extra 1 array (empty or not) for every match found

Reference: [Get xpath() to return empty values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459820/get-xpath-to-return-empty-values)

```
        sizes = []
        for i, data_row in enumerate(table_rows):
            if i == 0:
                sizes = data_row.xpath('./th/text()').getall(default='size-not-found')
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure of a more elegant way, but could you kludge it with something like: `sizes = [th.text or 'not-found' for th in data_row.xpath('./th')]`? Maybe try `data_row.css('th::text').getall()` but I imagine that'll translate to the same xpath that's already excluded the th tag with no text.

Comment: thx ... will try. Seems strange getall() does not have a default value

Comment: In the case here - I don't see how it could implement a default for getall... it just doesn't see that empty text element so it can't know there's something it should 
 have default filled... if there's nothing returned - should it have returned 2 defaults for your example instead? At least with get it's a simple "Did I get an element? Yes: return that... No: return the default instead"

Comment: Almost there `sizes = [th.xpath('./text()') or 'not-found' for th in data_row.xpath('./th')]` ... this part does not seem correct it is not returning string values `th.xpath('./text()')`

Comment: That's not what I posted in the comment though...

Comment: .text result in unknown attribute

Comment: Ahh... it's scrapy's wrapper around things isn't it... okay... try using `th.root.text` so you're accessing the `.text` attribute of the lxml'd object

Comment: Thats the trick ` sizes = [th.root.text or 'not-found' for th in data_row.xpath('./th')]` although I dont fully understand .... and my personal opinion is that it would be greagt if we could pass a default value to getall()... thanks. Please add to answer so I can accept

Comment: I don't think adding a default to `.getall` is practical as I mentioned above... I'll put the above down as an answer in a bit but it's very much a work around... I'm thinking there must be someway to do it in the xpath itself.

Comment: This was my assumption too ...could just not imagine I am the 1st to run into this